# Konsole starts in SU mode and asks for password in every window and tab

Tags: password, startup, su, konsole

I am a bit of a newby and I have stumbled upon an annoying thing. Everytime I open a konsole, it is in su and asks for my password. I have searched around and tried all the things recommended on this website and other to stop the console from starting in su mode. However, without succes.

My .bashrc is empty and does not hold su commands.

When typing: pstree -als $$ I get the following:

```
linux-ffd2:~ # pstree -als $$     
systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 24    
└─kdeinit5                                    
  └─konsole  
      └─su -  
          └─bash  
              └─pstree -als 26609
```

So there must be a su command hidden somewhere but I cannot find it. Can anybody help me get rid of it so I can start the konsole without su and without password? Thanks!

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: It sounds like your profile is configured as a "root konsole" - see for example [Konsole - Profile Management](https://userbase.kde.org/Konsole#Profile_Management)

Comment: @steeldriver you are right. My colleague just dropped in and found this was the issue. In Settings > Manage Profiles > Edit profile > General, ' Command'  was on su - and I had to change it to /bin/bash.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comments above the following was the matter:
In Settings > Manage Profiles > Edit profile > General it is important that in 'Command'  it does not say su- but /bin/bash.

Now the problem is solved.